# Name is local and global syntax error in python

Tags: python

I am getting error while executing below statement

```
a = 10

def test_method(a):
    global a
    print("Old value of local a = " + str(a)) #this is returning "a = 10"
    a = 2
    print("New value of local a = " + str(a))

test_method(a)
print("Value of global a = " + str(a))
```

Output

```
SyntaxError: name 'a' is local and global
```

How to change value of a globally in this proc where name is same for function argument and actual parameter

Comment: Just pick a different name for the function argument?

Comment: What if I am having same name

Comment: What's forcing you to use the same name for both?

Comment: I see some formatting errors that might confuse readers, please correct them (missing def, output unclear...)

Comment: @arshajii: There is nothing forcing me. I got stuck to issue while doing something. Thought if there is some way other than changing names.

Answer (score 1):

I really think the correct answer is to just pick a different name for the function argument as I commented, but if you cannot for some reason, you can access the global `a` via [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
>>> a = 10
>>> def test_method(a):
...     print('global:', globals()['a'])
...     print('local: ', a)
... 
>>> test_method(42)
global: 10
local:  42
```

Although this is somewhat hacky and I would strongly recommend simply changing the variable names to avoid the error instead.

Comment: Thanks. But how we can change value inside the proc to reflect outside

Comment: @Nitesh `globals()['a'] = ...`